# How can I edit CSS of embedded style sheets in HTML?

Tags: html, css, google-sheets, iframe

I am trying to embed a google sheet in my HTML document, but I need to format it's CSS. How can I edit its CSS?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Your question is way to broad. what HTML document, what google sheet? what exsisting css file? what prevents you from simply creating a custom css file? what prevents you from editing an excisting one?

Answer (score 1):

you aren’t allowed much control over the appearance of your spreadsheet – which can be inconvenient if you want to direct viewers to a particular part of the sheet.It's better you try features of the sheet to change appearance.

Comment: Is there a way to add a table with dynamic data in HTML?